# Backup tool for Ubuntu applications similar to one offered by Linux Mint

Tags: backup

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and, recently, I installed Linux Mint 20 in an old PC (just to take a look at it).

I noticed that Linux Mint comes with a backup tool that allows for software backup: basically, I can save the applications I have in my system so I won't have to reinstall them in case I have to restore the system or switch from a computer to another. I tried to look for a similar possibility in Ubuntu but I didn't find any. I was even thinking to switch to Linux Mint just for this tool.

Do you maybe have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you maybe referring to the possibility of making a backup of the folders where the applications are stored? I might be wrong but Deja Dup only offers the possibility to backup folders, not files or packages. I know I can easily reinstall the applications but now I'm trying different Linux distros (all Debian based) and it would be great to just transfer all my apps from one OS to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely referring to the [**Timeshift**](https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift) application.

You can install it on Ubuntu 20.04 too. It's available in the universe repo. If [universe is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/480481), you can install it by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install timeshift
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of the Timeshift application, however it restores the entire system. So, for example, if I want to move my .deb applications from one linux distro to another I can't do it since Timeshift will restore the whole OS from which the apps come from. Actually I'm not sure if it's even possible to do the thing I'm talking about, but I think I figured the solution: I can just save the list of .deb packages present here: /var/cache/apt/archives/ and transfer the files to the other distro. Is it feasible? I'm not an expert as you might have noticed...

Comment: That doesn't sound feasible, different distros usually have different sources and versions of packages.